# Use Google AppMaker with PHP

Tags: php, google-app-maker

I want to know if is possible to use Google App Maker with PHP to obtain a file from an specific folder of my PC and know if the file change.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *Anything* is possible. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1):

No.

Google App Maker creates web applications which run on the Google Cloud Platform, and which are accessed in a web browser. These applications cannot view files which are stored on your computer.